# mysql query returns empty set when data is there

Tags: mysql, sql, database

```
+----+---------+--------------------+----------+------+---------------------+---------+-------------+------------+----------+
| id | pname   | pmail              | pgender  | page | pdetails            | pnumber | ddepartment | date       | time     |
+----+---------+--------------------+----------+------+---------------------+---------+-------------+------------+----------+
|  1 | karuna  |  karuna@gmail.com  |  female  |   21 |  hfsdh gfhdf  shdh  |    2332 |  Surgeon    | 2018-05-15 | 16:00:00 |
+----+---------+--------------------+----------+------+---------------------+---------+-------------+------------+----------+
```

This is my database table `appointment`.

Whenever I execute first two queries, they run perfectly

```
select * from appointment;(execute )

select * from appointment where pname = 'karuna';(execute)
```

but when I try to execute these two queries, the result I get is empty set

```
select *from appointment where pmail='karuna@gmail.com';(empty set (0.00 sec))

select *from appointment where ddepartment='Surgeon';(empty set (0.00 sec))
```

Comment: which data type are  the columns pmail and ddepartment ?

Comment: varchar(20) not null

Comment: could be there are some hidden char  .. try using like  instead  of=   .. eg:   ddepartment like ('%Surgeon%')

Comment: it worked.thank you